# Maven cargo jetty6x: is it possible to provide additional Jetty configuration?

Tags: maven, jetty, cargo

I have application launched using maven cargo plugin with jetty6x. I get `HTTP/1.1 413 FULL head` on certain requests. I found out, that I need to specify larger `headerBufferSize` (due to large request header size). Is there a way to provide it to the cargo configuration?

My cargo configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <contextPath>/${jetty.admin.context}</contextPath>
        <container>
            <containerId>jetty6x</containerId>
            <type>embedded</type>
        </container>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <cargo.servlet.port>${jetty.port}</cargo.servlet.port>
            </properties>
            <deployables>
                <deployable>
                    <properties>
                        <context>/http</context>
                    </properties>
                    <groupId>xxx.xxx.server</groupId>
                    <artifactId>http</artifactId>
                    <type>war</type>
                </deployable>
            </deployables>
        </configuration>
        <wait>false</wait>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-container</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-container</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to specify the additional configuration files and the directories where they go under

```
<configuration><configfiles>...
```

in the configuration of the cargo plugin

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305935/is-it-possible-to-supply-tomcat6s-context-xml-file-via-the-maven-cargo-plugin) or the [cargo site](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Configuration+files+option).