# Cargo embedded tomcat: custom context.xml

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, cargo

I am using cargo to automate war deployment on Tomcat. However, i get a trouble: i can`t replace default tomcat files with my custom as my files are copied first and then get overwritten by default. I spent hours for resolving this problem but nothing works. Here is my pom.xml

```
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                         <executions>
                             <execution>
                                 <id>replace-tomcat-users-xml</id>
                                 <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                 <goals>
                                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                 </goals>
                                 <configuration>
                                     <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}/conf/</outputDirectory>
                                     <resources>
                                         <resource>
                                             <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
                                             <includes>
                                                 <include>context.xml</include>
                                             </includes>
                                         </resource>
                                     </resources>
                                 </configuration>
                             </execution>
                             <execution>
                                 <id>replace-tomcat-users-xml-cargo</id>
                                 <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                 <goals>
                                     <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                 </goals>
                                 <configuration>
                                     <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/cargo/installs/tomcat-${version.tomcat}/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}</outputDirectory>
                                     <resources>
                                         <resource>
                                             <directory>src/test/resources/</directory>
                                             <includes>
                                                 <include>context.xml</include>
                                             </includes>
                                         </resource>
                                     </resources>
                                 </configuration>
                             </execution>
                         </executions>
                     </plugin>
```

and here is cargo using:

```
<plugin>
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                       <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                       <version>1.4.11</version>
                       <configuration>
                           <skip>false</skip>
                           <container>
                               <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                               <log>${project.build.directory}/cargo.log</log>
                               <artifactInstaller>
                                   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
                                   <version>${version.tomcat}</version>
                                   <type>zip</type>
                               </artifactInstaller>
                               <systemProperties>
                                   <tomcat.home.dir>
                                       ${basedir}/target/cargo/installs/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}
                                   </tomcat.home.dir>
                                   <tomcat.server.home.dir>
                                       ${basedir}/target/cargo/installs/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}/apache-tomcat-${version.tomcat}
                                   </tomcat.server.home.dir>
                               </systemProperties>
                               <dependencies>
                                   <dependency>
                                       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                                       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                                   </dependency>
                               </dependencies>
                           </container>
                           <configuration>

                               <configfile>
                                   <file>${basedir}/target/cargo/installs/context.xml</file>
                                   <todir>conf/</todir>
                                   <tofile>context.xml</tofile>
                                   <configfile>true</configfile>
                                   <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                               </configfile>
                               <properties>
                                   <cargo.servlet.port>8080</cargo.servlet.port>
                                   <!--Тут менять-->
                                   <cargo.servlet.users>admin:admin:manager-script</cargo.servlet.users>
                                   <cargo.jvmargs>
                                       -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
                                       -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
                                       -Xnoagent
                                       -Djava.compiler=NONE
                                   </cargo.jvmargs></properties>
                           </configuration>
```

Comment: i see that i dont have here tag <configfiles> but i did that, so dont expext to find mistake here. The main problem is that embedded tomcat are copied later then my custom files and overrides them.

Answer (score 5):

One of solution is here: [Is it possible to supply Tomcat6's context.xml file via the Maven Cargo plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305935/is-it-possible-to-supply-tomcat6s-context-xml-file-via-the-maven-cargo-plugin#4417945)

My working configuration (with jdbc DataSource pool) looks like:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
                        <spring.profiles.active>tomcat,datajpa</spring.profiles.active>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <configfiles>
                        <configfile>
                            <file>src/main/resources/tomcat/context.xml</file>
                            <todir>conf/Catalina/localhost/</todir>
                            <tofile>context.xml.default</tofile>
                        </configfile>
                    </configfiles>
                </configuration>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <groupId>ru.javawebinar</groupId>
                        <artifactId>topjava</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <properties>
                            <context>${project.build.finalName}</context>
                        </properties>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```